Pool Light GFCI Not Working
We recently received a home inspection report that indicated the pool light GFCI is not working and poses a shock hazard. Our pool cleaners says they can fix this and addressed the issue, and the pool light is now operational, but they're not electricians and English isn't their first language so I'm nervous about any misunderstandings. If the pool light works, does that mean the pool light GFCI is now working properly? Or should we schedule out an electrician to take a look at the matter?
I appreciate any guidance that can be provided on this matter!

What does "not working" mean? Not passing power? Not tripping when tested? Not protecting downstream devices? Please revise to explain that better. You definitely don't want unlicensed people working on your wiring going forward, no matter how nice the offer.

Unfortunately they didn't leave a lot of details in the inspection report :( This was all they put in the home inspection report  https://postimg.cc/RNpHTztR

It'll be difficult to give you an answer, then. You'd have to lay out the circuit for us to analyze. The light being on does not prove that the GFCI is protecting anything.

Depending on the age of your pool you may have a 12V pool light and the GFCI only powers the transformer.   Far more info is needed here.  You could ask the inspector to expand on his finding.

Thank you for the responses. It sounds like an electrician is in order to ensure safety. I'll reach out to the inspector for any additional information he might have.

Or turn off the breaker, open the junction box and get some photos, and show us. It may be fine once we talk through it.

Is the light plug-in or hardwired? If plug-in then it is easy to test the GFCI functionality with a GFCI tester. If it is hardwired then it is a bit more complicated.

Appreciate the input! I grabbed these two photos of where our pool man was showing how the GFCI was working and stated it was fine and no issues but he wasn't able to explain how to tell when it isn't working due to the language barrier. He flicked it on and off and pointed at the light a lot :(    https://ibb.co/98kW76Q and https://ibb.co/jrFX1k8

@Christie, in the second picture someone is pointing at a tripped breaker marked "lts". Does that breaker control the pool lights? And did the breaker trip as a result of pressing the test button on the breaker?

Yes, that breaker does control the pool lights! It seems like he did trip it? He turned on the lights, then clicked a button and I heard a click. He tried it a few times but couldn't quite explain it beyond saying that it was working fine. I would really appreciate understanding what it looks like when the GFCI isn't functioning and why based on him flicking it on and off, the GFCI appears to be working? Is it a matter of testing whether the breaker is tripping properly?
